# Equation numbering with subscripts

Tags: equations, numbering

Could anyone tell me, how can I obtain an equation numbering as displayed in the textsample? I am talking about `(4.1)_\pm`.

[image: E.DiBenedetto, Partial Differential Equations]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\tag{}` is what you need. Btw, please add a source you take the screenshot from.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried, but unfortunately \tag{} is not producing the desired result. It Looks like ((1)_-). Moreover, I would prefer a solution where the equation-number is determinier by Latex and not by myself, as I will need to refer to these equations later.

Comment: Please, the name is “Ennio De Giorgi”, with a space. Writing it “DeGiorgi”, US style, is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, the extract is not my work. And besides DeGiorgi-function classes are written like this, throughout the literature. Besides, this is not the topic here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
\begin{equation}
a = b \tag*{(\theequation)$_{\pm}$}\refstepcounter{equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c = d \tag*{(\theequation)$_{-}$}\refstepcounter{equation}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Agreed. My answer was just a quick and dirty trick to add section numbers to equation number while using article.

Comment: @Denis - I've taken the liberty of editing your code to modify the way the composite "numbering" of equations is performed.